# rar command works from the command prompt but not from a batch file - no strange characters involved except for - and spaces (yes I use quotes)

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, rar

This is confusing me big time... Even when I copy-paste below command from the command prompt to Notepad or Notepad++ (with simple character encoding) and use it as a bat file, I get this error:

```
Kan CRYPTO\==.rar niet openen
The system cannot find the path specified.
Gebruik:   rar <opdracht> -<schakeloptie 1> -<schakeloptie N> <archief>
               <bestanden...> <@bestandslijst...> <uitpakpad\>

<Opdrachten>
```

Command used in cmd.exe (which works):

```
rar -rr100% a -k -os -ao -t -r -u -ma5 -m5 -htb -qo+ -ts -ep2 -se -ver10 -ag+YYYYMMDD_incr_ "E:\= RAIN\OneDrive\= CRYPTO\== Wallet Backups\E-Wallets Winrar Incremental Backup.rar" "E:\*wallet*.dat" "E:\*wallet*.bak" "E:\*wallet*.old"
```

Command as used in the batch file (which fails):

```
@echo off
c:
cd\
cd c:\
cd "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\"

rar -rr100% a -k -os -ao -t -r -u -ma5 -m5 -htb -qo+ -ts -ep2 -se -ver10 -ag+YYYYMMDD_incr_ "E:\= RAIN\OneDrive\= CRYPTO\== Wallet Backups\E-Wallets Winrar Incremental Backup.rar" "E:\*wallet*.dat" "E:\*wallet*.bak" "E:\*wallet*.old"
pause
```

I do not understand why this would be or how I could escape which characters... Despite googling for a bit now :)

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try `rar -rr100%%` in your batch file, maybe?

Comment: Frack, that must be it. Sigh. My bad (unless I repost) ;-) ♥

Comment: Good luck, then. =)